# Javascript convert text to object with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following text taken from a email body, I want to save each block into a object, then add into a array. but I am struggle to correctly define the for loop, in another word how to seprate the blocks

```
Name: Andy
Computer: ABC
IP: 192.168.0.1
Added By: Maria
Timestamp: 2018-03-15 08:45:08 +0000 UTC

Name: Richard
Computer: CDE
IP: 192.168.0.2
Timestamp: 2018-03-15 08:45:08 +0000 UTC

..........more blocks................
```

In **Javascript** (Jquery can not be supported)

```
//I first define a array  
var msgs= [];

//then define a object
var msg= {
    Name:"",
    Computer:"",
    IP:50,
    TimeStamp: new Date()
};

var reg = (.....);
var result;

//wholeMsgBody is the whole text sample I have provided
while((result = reg.exec(wholeMsgBody)) !== null) {
  //assume the block = Name:.... until TimeStamp.....
  var userName = block.match(Name:.*); //Andy
  var computer = block.match(Computer:.*); //ABC
  var ip = block.match(Computer:.*) //192.168.0.1
  Var timeStamp = new Date(block.match(Timestamp:.*)) //2018/03/15

  msgs.push({"Name":userName, "Computer":computer, "ip":ip, "timeStamp":timeStamp})
}
```

I am basiclly Struggle to define the reg expression. any help would be much appriciated.

Comment: What is your struggle? Please show us what you tried and what problem you were facing specifically.

Comment: You don't really need a regex (it might actually be more complicated to use one since this format may not necessarily be regular) it would be easier to just looking at the first word of a line, you know name means new object and then you know the order of the data values afterwards, you could just create a while loop that goes line by line and parses the data (using regex or whatever)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to separate the blocks by calling `split()` on the string and passing the appropriate separator. After this you can split it into lines, and then key/value pairs.

Of course, if your data is not consistent you will need to adjust, but something like this might get you started:

```js
var str = `Name: Andy
Computer: ABC
IP: 192.168.0.1
Added By: Maria
Timestamp: 2018-03-15 08:45:08 +0000 UTC

Name: Richard
Computer: CDE
IP: 192.168.0.2
Timestamp: 2018-03-15 08:45:08 +0000 UTC
`

var blocks = str.split('\n\n')
var objects = blocks.map(b => {
    let lines = b.split('\n')
    return lines.reduce((obj, line) => {
        if (!line) return obj
        let [key, value] = line.split(/:(.+)/)
        obj[key] = value.trim()
        return obj
    }, {})

})
console.log(objects)
```